# Eidolons and weapons with the Trip trait

Tags: magic-items, pathfinder-2e, summoner, eidolon

An [Eidolon's attacks can be enhanced](https://2e.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=1581) by your handwraps of mighty blows (Secrets of Magic, p53):

> Alternatively, you can Invest a magic weapon (even though magic weapons can't normally be Invested) to **share its fundamental and property runes with your eidolon**

Weapons with the [Trip](https://2e.aonprd.com/Traits.aspx?ID=196) trait add the "***weapon's item bonus** to attack rolls as an item bonus **to the Athletics check***" (CRB p283).

The item bonus comes from the fundamental rune, which is shared. So if the Summoner invests a +1 Sickle, does the Eidolon get a bonus to Trip attempts?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No.

The text for trip says:

> **You can use this weapon to Trip** with the Athletics skill even if you don't have a free hand. **This uses** the weapon's reach (if different from your own) and adds the weapon's item bonus to attack rolls as an item bonus to the Athletics check.

The text says that you can use the weapon to trip and that "This uses" the weapon's reach and adds the item bonus to the Athletics check. Therefore you have to be using the weapon for the trip. You might be inclined to say that the eidolon is sort of using the weapon by virtue of you being invested, but I would counter with the fact that eidolons have their own unarmed attacks, and their unarmed attacks can even start with the trip trait. If your eidolon has an attack with the trip trait they would add your weapon's item bonus to that check.

Comment: I agree; providing a bonus to Trip attempts is a function of the weapon traits, not the fundamental rune itself, which are not shared.